# Customers using paypal not receiving magento order confirmation

Tags: paypal, ce-1.9.2.4, order-confirmation

We are using CE1.9.2.4 with all patches installed.
We offer Paypal express checkout as a form of payment. Customers who are paying with paypal are not receiving the Magento order confirmation after completing payment and their order. 
We have checked our settings and they appear to be correct. We are receiving the payment IPN and the payment, and the order is showing as processing.
The problem is only with paypal payments, customers using a credit card are no problem.

Comment: can you try with `paypal website standard` option instead of `express checkout` ?

Comment: We do not want to use paypal for credit cards, we use authorize.net for credit cards and have no problems

Comment: check with hosting team once , also if you are using cpanel check whether any files are infected..... also make sure order confirmation email working for other payment methods.....

Comment: we have done all of that and problem is only with paypal